# Assetic files not merged into one in production

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm using Assetic for managing assets in the Symfony 3.0 framework. it work fine in dev mode, each file is processed individually. But in prod mode, assets are not combined into single file.

```
assetic:
debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    uglifyjs2:
        bin: "%npm_bin%/uglifyjs"
        apply_to:   '\.js$'
    uglifycss:
        bin: "%npm_bin%/uglifycss"
        apply_to:   '\.css$'
    closure:
       jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    yui_css:
       jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

[image]

```
symfony/symfony: v3.0.9 
symfony/assetic-bundle: v2.8.2
```

Comment: You might have different configuration for prod - dev and 'default'. Have you checked that already?

Comment: use [Encore Webpack](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend.html) in case of merging assets ...

Comment: @DominicWehrmann, No, I customized assetic only in dev :
    use_controller: false

Comment: @Trix, I used the same configuration in another project and everything works fine. The files are combined without the use of Encore.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing (in web/app.php)

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```